# HTML source editor BigCommerce admin

Tags: bigcommerce

I have an issue with HTML source editor in BigCommerce Admin panel.
When I try to add some html code to a page, it just deletes part of code.

For example:

I want to add the "allowfullscreen" attribute, and paste this code into  HTML source editor.

```
<iframe width="700px" height="425px" src="http://online.fliphtml5.com/afymr/pcav/#p=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then I tap Update button. But when I try to open this code again I have only

```
<iframe width="700px" height="425px" src="http://online.fliphtml5.com/afymr/pcav/#p=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

without allowfullscreen attribute, and my code doesn't work correctly.

I have the same issue with different HTML code examples. HTML source editor deletes parts of a code.

What should I do for fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using webdav for blueprint, or developing stencil locally so you don't have to deal with the admin area source editor?

Comment: The admin area source editor does have some bugs. I found one in JS that refused to accept my edits in the way I intended causing a failure too. But FTP'ing the file directly uploaded correctly. However, if anyone then edited the page to alter something else, the error re-appeared. The only solution was to put a massive comment on the top explaining why this file could not be edited and saved via the editor. I hope you solve your issue. BC is a PITA at times.